# how to fix bad sectors on Kingston USB in MAC OS

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I have an issue with my USB drive Kingston 64Go, I used it correctly 2 days ago, but suddenly I can't get access and I have sensible data I don't want to lose.

- It didn't appear in Finder (can't be mounted)
- Can't run first aid
  [image]
- I run fdisk and I get:

[image]

- Also I run:

[image]

Please, If anyone can help me I appreciate it a lot.

Thank you so much

Comment: 1. Reboot your system with the **USB** _device_ disconnected. 2. Connect the **USB** _device_. 3. Does it mount and is it readable? If not, then I'd try connecting it to a different computer to see if the results are the same.  Back in my **Windows** days when I couldn't read a disk under it, I'd try reading it on a **Linux** machine and many times I could read it and recover _data_ from **Linux** when not being able to under **Windows**. Then dealt with repairing the disk.

Comment: I tried what you suggest but it doesn't work, I plug it in a windows computer, I have the same thing: not mounted and in disk management unallocated

Comment: How is the volume on the drive formatted? FAT32, ExFAT or something else?

Comment: The volume is FAT32.

Comment: The repair command would not be `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk2`. The correct command would be `diskutil repairvolume disk2s1`.

Comment: Started file system repair on disk2s1 KINGSTON
Repairing file system
Volume is already unmounted
Performing fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk2s1
** /dev/rdisk2s1
Can't open (Resource busy)
File system check exit code is 8
Restoring the original state found as unmounted
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8

Comment: I'd see if Disk Drill can find anything on it; then throw it away. SD cards/USB sticks have a remarkable propensity for just dying, suddenly & totally. They are not worth the effort once they start to play up. Golden Rule: Never use these things to store the only copy of any data. If the data was valuable, you might want to try a data recovery specialist.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think the problem is in GPT if I can fix it I will have access to my data... I can't throw it away because I have a sensitive data :( and I want to repair them

Comment: How did you format it initially? It would be unusual for a FAT32 SD/USB to be GPT formatted, it would normally just be MBR.

Comment: By default is FAT32 but if you can see in the screenshot, it mentioned GPT

Comment: GPT/GUID is a partition structure, not a volume format. FAT32 technically can be on either, but MBR is more 'traditional'. Which you have will depend on exactlt how your formatted it. diskutil can't find a partition method, so it's assuming it ought to be GPT. It may or may not be correct, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Tetsujin I found this in system information => USB => Kingston Data Traveler :   Partition Map Type: MBR (Master Boot Record)
So it is MBR

Comment: You're still down to whether Disk Drill can find anything, or whether the data is valuable enough to warrant a data recovery service. Then throw it away.

Comment: Yes, Disk Drill found my data, I have to buy a key to recover it.